# TypeScript doesn't recognize destructuring when target is ES5

Tags: typescript, es6-shim

I'm using TypeScript with `"target": "es5"`. I'm also using `es6-shim`, and I have installed the `es6-shim/index.d.ts` file. That's all fine. My question is why I get an error when I try to do the following:

```
const map = new Map<string, number>([
    ['A', 1],
    ['B', 2]
]);
```

The error looks like this:

[image: TypeScript Map error]

However, if I "cast" the array to explicitly state that it contains tuples of string/number pairs, then it works:

```
const map = new Map<string, number>(<[string, number][]>[
    ['A', 1],
    ['B', 2]
]);
```

On the other hand, if I change my compiler setting to `"target": "es6"`, then again the error goes away and no cast is required.

So my question is, why can't the compiler figure out that the array contains string/number tuples when in es5 mode? Is there a way to "fix" it so that no cast is required?

**Edit**

Here's my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution to your problem? I'm also experiencing this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use TypeScript and target it to es5 and still use features such as Map, you do need to use a polyfill or a shim as you are using.

TypeScript can't know you're using that. But you can tell the compiler to allow it by copying the lib.es6.d.ts in your project.

When you install TypeScript using npm, there will be a file called lib.es6.d.ts, just copy it into your typings or src folder and it should work.

One other file you might want to copy is the lib.core.es6.d.ts, if you'd like to use things such as Object.assign

**Edit:**

One other option is to install the typings for the es6-shim:

```
typings install es6-shim --ambient --save
```

Comment: Instead of copying over the lib.es6.d.ts file, I would prefer to just change the compiler target to es6. That seems like an easier way to get the same result.That might be what I end up doing, but I was hoping that I could leave the target set to es5 and use the es6-shim type definitions because they state exactly what es6-shim provides. Setting the target to es6, would tell the compiler that I'm supporting a bunch of features that aren't necessarily there at runtime.

Comment: That would be the best. The only issue if you target es6, is that the javascript generated would be ES6 valid. For instance, if you had an arrow function, after compiling it would still use the arrow syntax, same thing for let, const, etc... In that case, I'd recommend recompile your code once again using babel

Comment: I'm already using babel. I'm conducting an experiment to see if I can still write the same code and have it run on all the same browsers without using babel.

Actually, I'm starting to see the benefit of copying over the lib.es6.d.ts file like you said. By doing that, I can still compile to es5 but also be able to reference es6 functionality.

Comment: I updated the answer. Actually, you can target TypeScript to es5 and just install the typings for es6-shim. This would have the same effect.

Comment: That's what I'm already doing! I explain that in the second sentence of my question. Running `typings install es6-shim --ambient --save` will create the `es6-shim/index.d.ts` file.

Comment: Sorry. So there's an error even with the typings installed?Can you post your tsconfig.json file?